# Select rows with highest value in one column in SQL

Tags: sql

in MySQL, I am trying to select one row for each "foreign_id". It must be the row with the highest value in column "time" (which is of type DATETIME). Can you help me how the SQL SELECT statement must look like? Thank you!
This would be really great! I am already trying for hours to find a solution :(

This is my table:

```
primary_id | foreign_id | name | time
----------------------------------------------------
1          | 3          | a    | 2017-05-18 01:02:03
2          | 3          | b    | 2017-05-19 01:02:03
3          | 3          | c    | 2017-05-20 01:02:03
4          | 5          | d    | 2017-07-18 01:02:03
5          | 5          | e    | 2017-07-20 01:02:03
6          | 5          | f    | 2017-07-18 01:02:03
```

And this is what the result should look like:

```
primary_id | foreign_id | name | time
----------------------------------------------------
3          | 3          | c    | 2017-05-20 01:02:03
5          | 5          | e    | 2017-07-20 01:02:03
```

I tried to order the intermediate result by time (descending) and then to select only the first row by using LIMIT 1. But like this I cannot get one row for each foreign_id.

Another try was to first order the intermediate result by time (descending) and then to GROUP BY foreign_id. But the GROUP BY statement seems to be executed **before** the ORDER BY statement (I received the rows with primary_id 1 and 4 as a result, not 3 and 5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
From my_table A
INNER JOIN (SELECT foreign_id, Max(time) AS time FROM my_table GROUP BY foreign_id) B
ON A.foreign_id = B.foreign_id AND A.time = B.time
```

Comment: If the table has multiple rows for the same foreign key with identical time stamp, this query will return all such entries.

Comment: I don't think `DISTINCT` is necessary, since there is a PK on the table, so all rows will be distinct anyway. Also, what @dasblinkenlight said.

Comment: Thank you, this works fine :) The timestamps cannot be the same in my case, there are always multiple minutes between them

Answer (score 0):

Just add some data sample to analyze special case

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`primary_id` int, `foreign_id` int, `name` varchar(1), `time` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`primary_id`, `foreign_id`, `name`, `time`)
VALUES
    (1, 3, 'a', '2017-05-18 01:02:03'),
    (2, 3, 'b', '2017-05-19 01:02:03'),
    (3, 3, 'c', '2017-05-20 01:02:03'),
 (7, 3, 'H', '2017-05-20 01:02:03'),
    (4, 5, 'd', '2017-07-18 01:02:03'),
    (5, 5, 'e', '2017-07-20 01:02:03'),
    (6, 5, 'f', '2017-07-18 01:02:03')
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38947b/6

```
select d.primary_id, d.foreign_id, c.name, d.time
from table1 c inner join (    
select max(b.primary_id) primary_id, a.foreign_id,   a.time  
 from table1 b inner join 
 ( select  foreign_id, max(time) time
from table1
group by foreign_id) a
on a.foreign_id = b.foreign_id and a.time=b.time
group by   a.foreign_id,  a.time  ) d
on c.primary_id=d.primary_id
```

Answer (score 0):

In days gone by you would code this as a correlated subquery:
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1 o
    WHERE primary_id = (
        SELECT min (m.primary_id) FROM Table1 m
        WHERE m.time= (
            SELECT max (i.time) FROM Table1 i
            WHERE o.foreign_id=i.foreign_id
            )
        )

The extra subquery handles the case of duplicate foreign_id & time values.  If you were sure that time was unique for each foreign_id you could omit the middle subquery.